# BTRFS snapshot fails with "No space left"

Tags: debian, btrfs, snapshot

While creating a BTRFS RAID10 subvolume snapshot, I hit:

```
[21816375.986061] ? btrfs_cleanup_transaction+0x530/0x530 [btrfs]
[21816375.986065] kthread+0x112/0x130
[21816375.986066] ? kthread_bind+0x30/0x30
[21816375.986070] ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
[21816375.986072] ---[ end trace a2d9b072102a4b9d ]---
[21816375.986116] BTRFS: error (device sdb) in btrfs_run_delayed_refs:2934: errno=-28 No space left
[21816375.986157] BTRFS info (device sdb): forced readonly
[21816375.986160] BTRFS warning (device sdb): Skipping commit of aborted transaction.
[21816375.986161] BTRFS: error (device sdb) in cleanup_transaction:1870: errno=-28 No space left
[21816376.167051] BTRFS error (device sdb): pending csums is 188416
```

It was a surprise for me, because I saw a lot of free and unallocated space:

```
Overall:
    Device size:                  87.32TiB
    Device allocated:             67.31TiB
    Device unallocated:           20.00TiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                         56.73TiB
    Free (estimated):             15.29TiB      (min: 15.29TiB)
    Data ratio:                       2.00
    Metadata ratio:                   2.00
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)

Data,RAID10: Size:33.57TiB, Used:28.28TiB
   /dev/sdb       11.19TiB
   /dev/sdc       11.19TiB
   /dev/sdd       11.19TiB
   /dev/sde       11.19TiB
   /dev/sdf       11.19TiB
   /dev/sdg       11.19TiB

Metadata,RAID10: Size:92.72GiB, Used:89.08GiB
   /dev/sdb       30.91GiB
   /dev/sdc       30.91GiB
   /dev/sdd       30.91GiB
   /dev/sde       30.91GiB
   /dev/sdf       30.91GiB
   /dev/sdg       30.91GiB

System,RAID10: Size:103.88MiB, Used:3.05MiB
   /dev/sdb       34.62MiB
   /dev/sdc       34.62MiB
   /dev/sdd       34.62MiB
   /dev/sde       34.62MiB
   /dev/sdf       34.62MiB
   /dev/sdg       34.62MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sdb        3.33TiB
   /dev/sdc        3.33TiB
   /dev/sdd        3.33TiB
   /dev/sde        3.33TiB
   /dev/sdf        3.33TiB
   /dev/sdg        3.33TiB
```

So in theory I expected to have at least 10TB free (3x3.33 on RAID10)

We did our first rebalance like this:

`btrfs fi balance start -dusage=5 /mnt`

And got this:

```
Overall:
    Device size:                  87.32TiB
    Device allocated:             56.86TiB
    Device unallocated:           30.45TiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                         56.21TiB
    Free (estimated):             15.54TiB      (min: 15.54TiB)
    Data ratio:                       2.00
    Metadata ratio:                   2.00
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)

Data,RAID10: Size:28.34TiB, Used:28.02TiB
   /dev/sdb        9.45TiB
   /dev/sdc        9.45TiB
   /dev/sdd        9.45TiB
   /dev/sde        9.45TiB
   /dev/sdf        9.45TiB
   /dev/sdg        9.45TiB

Metadata,RAID10: Size:92.72GiB, Used:81.35GiB
   /dev/sdb       30.91GiB
   /dev/sdc       30.91GiB
   /dev/sdd       30.91GiB
   /dev/sde       30.91GiB
   /dev/sdf       30.91GiB
   /dev/sdg       30.91GiB

System,RAID10: Size:7.88MiB, Used:2.58MiB
   /dev/sdb        2.62MiB
   /dev/sdc        2.62MiB
   /dev/sdd        2.62MiB
   /dev/sde        2.62MiB
   /dev/sdf        2.62MiB
   /dev/sdg        2.62MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sdb        5.08TiB
   /dev/sdc        5.08TiB
   /dev/sdd        5.08TiB
   /dev/sde        5.08TiB
   /dev/sdf        5.08TiB
   /dev/sdg        5.08TiB
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. What does it mean when "btrfs fi us" is showing a lot of "Unallocated" space, and yet we ran into the out of space issue (probably on Metadata data - subvolume snapshot), why isn't Metadata expanding into that Unallocated space automatically?
2. Should we run regularly (how often) btrfs balance?
3. What is an optimal value for -dusage ?
4. Is it dangerous and should we rebalance metadata: -musage=5 for example?
5. We understand btrfs uses low level chunks for data/metadata allocation, but we don't if there is a way to monitor their usage somehow?